# Is it OK to edit a closed question that has no answer to be a totally new question?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, edits, closed-questions

Is it OK to edit a closed question, which does not have a single answer, to be a totally new question?

I am referring to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727626/mysql-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-column-name-isnt-in-group-by
and its [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40727626/revisions). The question was closed as a duplicate, but has no answer. The OP has edited it to create a new and different question. There is some controversy in the comments about whether or not this is OK.

Is it OK? What's our policy on this?

Comment: i don't believe so because the question has been answered as indicated by the duplicate link

Comment: Apparently some want to reopen thus causing others the inability to close vote the subsequent Chameleon question. Good luck finding harmonious agreement.

Comment: @Memor-X the question has no answer on it.

Comment: Sure it does. If it stands up the answer is in the dupe target.

Comment: How useful is an encyclopedia that at first has an article about zebras on page 30, and then, ten minutes later, that article is now about iguanas, because the person who wrote that page is no longer interested in zebras but is fascinated with iguanas?

Comment: @YvetteColomb *"the question has been answered **as indicated by the duplicate link**"*. if the duplicate linked question(s) do not answer the question then the OP need to edit their question as to why the solutions there wont work to get their question re-opened

Comment: I actually don't know what the right thing is to do, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @Memor-X you're missing the point, I'm asking about closed questions generally being edited to ask a new question. A different question.

Comment: As far as I know, the policy is that substantively changing a question like that isn't okay, because it makes it impossible to find information about zebras.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that is true if it has an answer. I am not so sure about non answered questions, as we are always telling people to edit and improve.

Comment: Doesn't the linked duplicate have a positively-voted answer?

Comment: This question does not affect the linked dupe target, they are totally separate

Comment: Rev 2 of the question which merely changed the tag iirc happened, then the dupe close. The OP took the info from the close reason and changed the question because a new and different error occurs. It is not our job to babysit this musical chairs approach to question asking / changing.

Comment: I gotta get back to work, we'll see what people come up with, hopefully some interesting discussion and a definitive answer so we can refer to that in the future

Comment: The closed question's answer is located in the linked dupe target. That is the purpose of dupe closures.

Comment: @YvetteColomb aside from duplicate closures? i don't believe so either. edits are meant to improve questions/answers. if you have a new one of either you post it as a new one, not recycle an old ones. if someone finds old question by someone else with no answers and was closed for whatever reason and edits it to ask something totally different it would be reverted back too. in my view just because the editor is the post author isn't an exception

Answer (score 26, accepted):

General policy is: don't waste folks' time.

- Don't change a question to something irrelevant after answers have been posted.
- Don't edit comments to say something different after someone's responded.
- And don't mess around with Jim.

I'd say this falls into the same boat: if the question were *still open*, then editing it to not be a duplicate would be fine; no one else would have to close vote, so overall it would save time. But... Since it's already closed, might as well just post a new question - that way no one has to reopen it.

O'course, Drew's probably wasted more time *arguing about this* than he would've by just reopening the question, so right now *everyone involved* is wasting time unnecessarily here.

Comment: Thanks mate, I wanted a clear answer so we can stop debating it and just get on with it and now we have a post to bookmark and say, see here, the "Great Shog Says ..." Also, who's Jim?

Comment: If part of the "clear answer" here is that golds should reopen questions in these circumstances then I will be glad to stop close voting.

Comment: You could've reopened, @Drew; or you could've just asked the author to re-post the question separately; or you could've done nothing at all. Those were all things you could do at your discretion without getting others involved. Instead you got into a roll-back war and had to drag a mod in. No serious harm done, but certainly a lot more time spent on it than was really necessary; maybe you can learn something from this?

Comment: [Ask a fresh new question](http://i.imgur.com/LzbeuDO.jpg) . If rollbacks are also to be avoided, please advise.

Comment: @drew: [be advised.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/)

Comment: Two rollbacks, flagged a mod, and left. Then pings from others that wanted it reopened. That is my summary.

Comment: @Drew you pinged me in chat about it also ;)

Comment: @YvetteColomb I did because I was very confused why some higher rep people thought that changing a question after-the-fact made sense. So I sought other perspectives.

Comment: @Drew tbh I did not know the policy on editing answers in this situation

Comment: It's unfortunate that the party most likely to be doing the right thing (the one talking on meta, reading blogs, etc.) is the one most likely to follow the "let them have it their way" advice, resulting in users who care more about getting a private tutoring service than about contributing to SO getting the final say in determining what happens on SO.

Comment: What are you talking about, @TigerhawkT3?

Comment: ["However, __if the author of the post is resistant to your editing changes__, even a perfectly legitimate edit based on the above rules, be the bigger man (or woman) and _let them have it their way_."](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/)

Comment: If the lesson to be learned is that for a non-answered dupe close (excusing the fact that the dupe target might just answer it) that an OP wants to change the question and we reopen it, then that ought to be the answer above. The answer above at the moment says "don't  change the question after a close" then says Drew should have reopened it. That is the lesson that I have learned. A lesson of confusion. I will take that forward.

Comment: To be clear, I will reopen any changed dupe closure with no answers under it if people ping me so as not to argue with them.

Comment: The alternative is a spiral into chaos, @TigerhawkT3. If someone wants to shoot themselves in the foot, if they're *determined* to do that, then all you're gonna do by interfering is get yourself hurt. We have the luxury of patience.

Comment: Re-read it, @Drew. I said changing the question was a waste of time, and so was your bickering. You don't get to claim you're right because someone else was wrong, and he doesn't get his way just because you were wrong. You both had the power to make something more of the situation, and neither of you did.

Comment: I said "ask a fresh new question". Thanks for summarizing my service as nothing.

Comment: You could've closed the question and walked away forever and done exactly as much good as you did by coming back. So what did you gain, what service did you fulfill, by returning, @Drew? You want a pat on the back for getting into an argument you couldn't win? Sorry... "that's not how we roll here".

Comment: To return a question in a state that made sense with the close reason, flag, and move on. It was my community moderation. If I failed at that please forgive.

Comment: Isn't turning a zebra question with a zebra answer link into an iguana question with a zebra answer link already flirting with chaos? If a user shoots their question in the foot, it's SO's body that bleeds.

Comment: Who's Jim? We need to know!

Comment: @Seth: [You Don't Mess Around With Jim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4qUXcXuMSE)

Comment: @PM 2Ring - [*technically*](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1475:_Technically) it's Slim you don't mess around with. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Bear in mind that when a question is closed as a dupe, the system links the two questions together. Future readers will be able to find one question from the other by following the links in the `Linked` sidebar, as well as by following the link to the dupe target(s) in the dupe's `marked as duplicate` banner.

If an unanswered dupe gets reopened those links will be removed. (Thanks, Shog9 for that info). Closed dupes are kept alive to assist in navigating the site, so if the dupe can conceivably serve as a useful search target to help a future reader find the dupe target it makes sense to leave the dupe as it is and for the OP to simply ask a new question. And even if the dupe isn't a great search target there's no harm in leaving it as is, and little value in chameleoning it into a different question, IMHO.

Comment: Yep I didn't think of that at the outset, as I assumed it would be reopened. But good point

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm _pretty_ sure that the sidebar links remain if a dupe gets re-opened, but I'm asking other gold badgers about this in Chat, and I'll try to remember to check it next time I re-open a question, and if those links do disappear I'll amend this answer.

Comment: The sidebar links are created in two ways: from links in the posts or comments, and from duplicate targets. They should eventually be deleted when a question is reopened, unless they appear elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Thanks for that info @Shog9, I've amended my answer.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I've changed my answer in response to info from Shog9.